# Can't Permalink to text results in data explorer

Tags: bug, data-explorer, permalink

When you:

- compose a query in the Data Explorer
- check the Text-only results checkbox
- run the query

the permalink hyperlink looks like this:

https://data.stackexchange.com/user%20experience/query/136949?opt.textResults=true

However, that query string parameter `opt.textResults` appears to not be fully respected; clicking the above link takes you to a page where the Text-only results checkbox is *checked* but the query output is in *grid* form. You have to then click Run Query again to get text results.

Could we get a way of linking directly to a text-only run?

Comment: It's not that it's not respected exactly...the grid only shows up because the results happen to be cached, otherwise you'd have to rerun the query regardless. Still, I agree that it could be handled more intuitively, so I'll put it on the todo list.

Comment: Came here to post the same issue; not a big one, but would be nice. Requesting TODO list item bump @TimStone.

Comment: @TimStone 6-8 Friedmans?